# Get all Facebook photo albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Up until recently, just found out about 30 mins ago, when my app would call `https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/albums?access_token=<token>` Facebook would return all of the User's photo albums. Now, it is just giving 25.

I've tried adding the follow params to the url:
`&cursor=#`
`&c=#`
`&page=#`
`&p=#`
`&index=#`
`&i=#`
`&start=#`
`&s=#`

So the question, how do I get the rest of the albums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Graph API paginates what it returns. There is property in the JSON array returned called `paging`, which contains the URLs of the next and previous pages.

You should be able to see it by navigating to a URL such as what you gave, eg https://graph.facebook.com/facebook/albums